# Angular-UI-Router: ui-sref not building href with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an HTML page, once loaded in the user's browser the 'list' state is activated and the 'list' partial is pulled by Angular and populated with a list of servers.

Each server has a 'details' link that specifies the 'details' state for that server.

```
<td><a ui-sref="details({ serverName: '{{server.name}}' })">Details</a></td>
```

When rendered the 'ui-sref' generates the expected 'href' url based on the route and its optional parameters.

```
<a ui-sref="details({ serverName: 'SLCMedia' })" href="#/details/SLCMedia">Details</a>
```

When clicked it works as expected and the 'details' partial is pulled and in the controller assigned to that state pulls the server with the name specified.

The issue I am running into is the fact that once the 'details' partial is loaded, it too has a 'ui-sref' to an 'edit' state.

```
   <a ui-sref="edit({ serverName: '{{server.name}}' })">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-labeled btn-primary">
            <span class="btn-label icon fa fa-edit"></span>
            Edit
        </button>
    </a>
```

But when this partial is loaded the 'ui-sref' is not generating the correct 'href' url.

```
   <a ui-sref="edit({ serverName: 'SLCMedia' })" href="#/edit/">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-labeled btn-primary">
            <span class="btn-label icon fa fa-edit"></span>
            Edit
        </button>
    </a>
```

As you can see the 'href' url is '#/edit/' not '#/edit/SLCMedia' as would be expected. It's got to be something simple that I am missing. Does the change of state have something to do with it?

Here are all of defined 'states' for the page.

```
// Create the Angular App to rule the Server Management Page
var serverApp = angular.module('serverApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'serverControllers',
    'utilitiesService'
]);

serverApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/list");

    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('list', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: '/views/pages/servers/list.html',
            controller: 'serverListCtrl'
        })
        .state('details', {
            url: '/details/:serverName',
            templateUrl: '/views/pages/servers/details.html',
            controller: 'serverDetailsCtrl'
        })
        .state('create', {
            url: '/create',
            templateUrl: '/views/pages/servers/create.html'
        })
        .state('edit', {
            url: '/edit/:serverName',
            templateUrl: '/views/pages/servers/edit.html',
            controller: 'serverEditCtrl'
        })
});
```

Here are my controllers

```
var serverControllers = angular.module('serverControllers', ['utilitiesService']);

serverControllers.controller('serverListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/servers/getList').success(function (data) {
        $scope.serverList = data;
    });
});

serverControllers.controller('serverDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
    var serverName = $stateParams.serverName;

    $http.get('/servers/getServerByName/' + serverName).success(function (data) {
        $scope.server = data;
    });
});

serverControllers.controller('serverEditCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $state, showAlertMessage) {
    var serverName = $stateParams.serverName;

    $http.get('/servers/getServerByName/' + serverName).success(function (data) {
        $scope.server = data;
    });

    $scope.server.submitForm = function (item, event) {
        console.log("--> Submitting Server Update");

        //TIMDO: Verify all required fields have been included

        var responsePromise = $http.post("/servers/postEdit", $scope.server, {});
        responsePromise.success(function(dataFromServer, status, headers, config) {
            showAlertMessage({
                type: 'success',
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Server information updated'
            });

            $state.go('clear');
        });
        responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            showAlertMessage({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Server information updated'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hmm, I'm probably misunderstanding your issue but I see at least one obvious difference between the look of your code and the look of mine.

My angular-ui-router links look like this:

```
<a ui-sref="reps-show({ id: rep.id })">{{rep.name}}</a>
```

The difference is the absence of braces around `rep.id`. So I wonder if changing this

```
<td><a ui-sref="details({ serverName: '{{server.name}}' })">Details</a></td>
```

to this

```
<td><a ui-sref="details({ serverName: server.name })">Details</a></td>
```

might do something for you.

That's probably not it but that's the first thing that came to mind for me.

Comment: Well, removing the wrapping braces {{}} worked! So that raises the question, why does it work with the braces on the list partial but not on the details partial? That I find completely odd behavior. And just to note, it still works on the list partial if I remove the {{}} as well.

Comment: I think it has to do with the ng-repeat which makes sure that first: the expressions are evaluated, then: the ui-sref kicks off it's magic.

Answer (score 0):

I created [simplified, but working version here](http://plnkr.co/edit/orXkKSkoCiQgGDx38FM1?p=preview). Because there is nothing obviously wrong. This example should at least help you to assure that:

> All you are trying to do is supposed to be working.

Here are states:

```
// States
$stateProvider
      .state('list', { 
          url: "/list",
          templateUrl: 'tpl.list.html',
          controller: 'serverListCtrl',
      })
      .state('edit', {
        url: '/edit/:serverName',
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        controller: 'serverEditCtrl'
    })
```

Here controller of a list loading data

```
.controller('serverListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('server.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.serverList = data;
    });
}])
```

(server.json) - example of data

```
[
  {"name":"abc"},
  {"name":"def"},
  {"name":"xyz"}
]
```

And the same template:

```
<li ng-repeat="server in serverList">
    <a ui-sref="edit({ serverName: '{{server.name}}' })">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-labeled btn-primary">
            <span class="btn-label icon fa fa-edit"></span>
            Edit {{server.name}}
        </button>
    </a>
</li>
```

All is working as expected. Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/orXkKSkoCiQgGDx38FM1?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I want to contribute with another datapoint in-case some other folks arrive here with a similar question, as I did.

I was using the non-curly-brace version in my app, and it wasn't working. My specifics involve the InfoWindow in **Google Maps**. I believe there is a rendering order "issue" such that the data required for the ui-sref link doesn't exist, and when it does finally exist, it's never "re-rendered".

**Original (non-working) version:**

```
%h3
  {{window_info.data.user.name || "Mystery Person"}}
%a.fa.fa-info-circle{ ui: { sref: 'users.show({id: window_info.data.user.id })' } }
%pre {{window_info.data.user.id | json}}
```

**Working version:**

```
%h3
  {{window_info.data.user.name || "Mystery Person"}}
%a.fa.fa-info-circle{ ui: { sref: "users.show({id: '{{ window_info.data.user.id }}' })" } }
%pre {{window_info.data.user.id | json}}
```

I placed the `%pre` tag with the info to prove to myself that the datum was in-fact present (at least ultimately/eventually), but even still the original code for the link was not working. I adjusted my code to use the interpolated curly-brace version as per the OPs situation and it worked.

**Conclusion:** Your solution could depend on the way in which the parent component is handling rendering. **Google Maps** in this case is fairly notorious for being "funky" (technical term) with rendering, particularly in Angu-land.